# The cofibration from the $\textbf{Top}$'s model category

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories

In $\textbf{Top}$'s model category structure, a maps is called a cofibration if it has the LLP with respect to acyclic fibrations (i.e. with
respect to each map which is both a Serre fibration and a weak homotopy equivalence).

I wonder why it is defined like this, are there any relations with the 'cofibration' is the usual sense?

Comment: Yes, there is a relation: Serre cofibrations are precisely retracts of relative CW-complexes.  The definition via lifting properties holds in any model category, not just Top.  Here is a reference: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+topological+spaces

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Thanks, I wonder why the Serre cofibration is dual to the Serre fibration.

Comment: Serre fibrations (respectively trivial Serre fibrations) are defined as maps with the RLP with respect to inclusions of disks into cylinders (respectively spheres into disks).  By the small object argument, Serre cofibrations (respectively trivial Serre cofibrations), which are defined using the LLP with respect to trivial Serre fibrations (respectively Serre fibrations), can be equivalently described as retracts of transfinite compositions of pushouts of inclusions of sphere into disks (respectively disks into cylinders).  This is all explained nicely via model categories, see Hovey's book.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Thanks, but you just gave the definition, I can not see the duality from your explanation and that book. And how do you define the duality? You see they are dual in what sense?

Comment: Serre fibrations and trivial fibrations can also be defined as maps with the RLP with respect to Serre trivial cofibrations and cofibrations, hence the duality.  In fact, the LLP/RLP correspondence defines an antitone Galois connection on sets of morphisms (which is where the duality comes from), and the closure operator takes a set of morphisms to the set of retracts of transfinite composition of pushouts.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Is this an equivalent definition for Hurewicz (co)fibration?

Comment: Yes, (closed) Hurewicz cofibrations and Hurewicz fibrations satisfy exactly the same type of property.  One must replace disks with arbitrary topological spaces.  This is known as the Stro̸m model structure.